# Accessing Devise user fields in React with React on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, devise, react-on-rails

I'm trying to access the Devise attribute `invitation_accepted_at` in my `Users` objects in Users#index. The devise attributes are returned in my controller method, as well as to the Rails view. But are being lost when passed over to React in the JSX state object.

**users_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
```

**users/index.html.erb**

```
<%= react_component("User", props: {
  users: @users
  }) %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'user' %>
```

**User.jsx**

```
// . . .

export default class User extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { users: this.props.users };
  }

// . . .
```

When I do a `console.log( this.state.users )`, I get the original objects, but without the Devise attributes.

Is this possible? Or am I missing steps?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are being impacted by the implicit hash conversion.  In a debug session of your controller, see what `@users.to_hash`is outputting (I believe it should match what you are seeing in your console log).  Try updating the value you are passing to react to be `@users.attributes` and see if that contains what you are looking for.